# How to get boxplot data for matplotlib boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to get the statistical data which were generated to draw a box plot in Pandas(using dataframe to create boxplots). i.e. Quartile1,Quartile2,Quartile3, lower whisker value, upper whisker value and outliers.
I tried the following query to draw the boxplot.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
pd.DataFrame.boxplot(df,return_type = 'both')
```

Is there a way to do it instead of manually calculating the values?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One option is to use the y data from the plots - probably most useful for the outliers (fliers)

```
_, bp = pd.DataFrame.boxplot(df, return_type='both')

outliers = [flier.get_ydata() for flier in bp["fliers"]]
boxes = [box.get_ydata() for box in bp["boxes"]]
medians = [median.get_ydata() for median in bp["medians"]]
whiskers = [whiskers.get_ydata() for whiskers in bp["whiskers"]]
```

But it's probably more straightforward to get the other values (including IQR) using either

```
quantiles = df.quantile([0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99])
```

or, as suggested by WoodChopper

```
stats = df.describe()
```

Answer (score 6):

- To get the boxplot data, use [`matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats), which returns a list of dictionaries of statistics used to draw a series of box and whisker plots using [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html)

  - To get the boxplot statistics, pass an `array` to `boxplot_stats`.

    - This is not specific to `pandas`.
- The default plot engine for `pandas`, is `matplotlib`, so using `boxplot_stats` will return the correct metrics for [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.box`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.box.html).
- Pass the **numeric columns** of interest, to `boxplot_stats`, as an `array`, using [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html).
- There can be no `NaN` values in the columns.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.1.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats
import numpy as np

# test dataframe
np.random.seed(346)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

# plot the dataframe as needed
ax = df.plot.box(figsize=(8, 6), showmeans=True, grid=True)
```

[image]

- Extract the boxplot metrics by passing an `array` to `boxplot_stats`

  - `boxplot_stats(df)` or `boxplot_stats(df.values)` will work.
  - The `dicts` are in the same order as the column arrays from `df`.
  - This data had no outliers, `fliers`, because it was generated with `numpy.random`.

```py
# create a dict of dicts with the column names as the keyword for each dict of statistics
stats = dict(zip(df.columns, boxplot_stats(df)))

print(stats)
[out]:
{'A': {'cihi': 0.6008396701195271,
       'cilo': 0.45316512285356997,
       'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
       'iqr': 0.47030110594253877,
       'mean': 0.49412631128104645,
       'med': 0.5270023964865486,
       'q1': 0.2603486498337239,
       'q3': 0.7306497557762627,
       'whishi': 0.9941975539538199,
       'whislo': 0.00892072823759571},
 'B': {'cihi': 0.5460977498205477,
       'cilo': 0.39283808760835964,
       'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
       'iqr': 0.4880880962171596,
       'mean': 0.47578540593013985,
       'med': 0.4694679187144537,
       'q1': 0.2466015651284032,
       'q3': 0.7346896613455628,
       'whishi': 0.9906905357196321,
       'whislo': 0.002613905425137064},
 'C': {'cihi': 0.6327876179340386,
       'cilo': 0.47317829117336885,
       'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
       'iqr': 0.5083099578365278,
       'mean': 0.5202481643792808,
       'med': 0.5529829545537037,
       'q1': 0.24608370844800756,
       'q3': 0.7543936662845353,
       'whishi': 0.9968264819096214,
       'whislo': 0.008450848029956215},
 'D': {'cihi': 0.5429786764060252,
       'cilo': 0.40089287519667627,
       'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
       'iqr': 0.4525025516221303,
       'mean': 0.4948030963370377,
       'med': 0.4719357758013507,
       'q1': 0.279181107815125,
       'q3': 0.7316836594372553,
       'whishi': 0.9836196084903415,
       'whislo': 0.019864664399723786},
 'E': {'cihi': 0.5413819754851169,
       'cilo': 0.3838462046931251,
       'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
       'iqr': 0.5017062764076173,
       'mean': 0.4922357500877824,
       'med': 0.462614090089121,
       'q1': 0.2490034171367362,
       'q3': 0.7507096935443536,
       'whishi': 0.9984043081918205,
       'whislo': 0.0036707224412856343}}
```