# How to annotate boxplot median, quartiles, and whiskers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a pandas dataframe containing data on Facebook Posts broken down by "type of post."  The dataframe is called "Posts_by_type"  It contains the # of likes, # of shares, and the type of post.  There are 3 types of post: Racing, Entertainment, and Promo.

I want to create a boxplot in matplotlib showing the # of Likes for each type of post.

My code works:

```
Posts_by_type.boxplot(column='Likes', by='Type', grid=True)
```

This produces the following boxplot:

[image]

HOWEVER, I also want to label the median and the whiskers on the boxplot with the corresponding numeric values.

Is this possible in matplotlib?  If so, can anyone give me some pointers on how to do it?

Comment: Two of the related questions show solutions to this problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38649932/4124317) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18861734/4124317). You would need to argue why they are not applicable in your case.

Answer (score 14):

A solution that also adds the values for the boxes.

```
import random
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_x_tick_labels(df, grouped_by):
    tmp = df.groupby([grouped_by]).size()
    return ["{0}: {1}".format(k,v) for k, v in tmp.to_dict().items()]

def series_values_as_dict(series_object):
    tmp = series_object.to_dict().values()
    return [y for y in tmp][0]

def generate_dataframe():
    # Create a pandas dataframe...
    _likes = [random.randint(0,300) for _ in range(100)]
    _type = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase[:5]) for _ in range(100)]
    _shares = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)]
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {'Likes': _likes,
         'Type': _type,
         'shares': _shares
        })

def add_values(bp, ax):
    """ This actually adds the numbers to the various points of the boxplots"""
    for element in ['whiskers', 'medians', 'caps']:
        for line in bp[element]:
            # Get the position of the element. y is the label you want
            (x_l, y),(x_r, _) = line.get_xydata()
            # Make sure datapoints exist 
            # (I've been working with intervals, should not be problem for this case)
            if not np.isnan(y): 
                x_line_center = x_l + (x_r - x_l)/2
                y_line_center = y  # Since it's a line and it's horisontal
                # overlay the value:  on the line, from center to right
                ax.text(x_line_center, y_line_center, # Position
                        '%.3f' % y, # Value (3f = 3 decimal float)
                        verticalalignment='center', # Centered vertically with line 
                        fontsize=16, backgroundcolor="white")

posts_by_type = generate_dataframe()


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 10))

bp_series = posts_by_type.boxplot(column='Likes', by='Type', 
                                  grid=True, figsize=(25, 10), 
                                  ax=axes, return_type='dict', labels=labels)
# This should return a dict, but gives me a Series object, soo...
bp_dict = series_values_as_dict(bp_series)
#Now add the values
add_values(bp_dict, axes)
# Set a label on X-axis for each boxplot
labels = get_x_tick_labels(posts_by_type, 'Type')
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
# Change some other texts on the graphs?
plt.title('Likes per type of post', fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel('Type', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Likes', fontsize=18)
plt.suptitle('This is a pretty graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `labels` variable should be defined before using it.

Answer (score 2):

- While [Labeling boxplot in seaborn with median value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38649501/7758804) is used as a reference, those answers will not work because the whiskers, as plotted by `matplotlib`, aren't easily calculated directly from the data.

  - As shown in [`matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html), the whiskers should be at `Q1-1.5IQR` and `Q3+1.5IQR`, however the whiskers are only drawn to those values when there are outliers. Otherwise a whisker is only drawn to the min value below `Q1`, and/or the max value above `Q3`.
  - Look at `days_total_bill.min()` to see that all the low whiskers are only drawn to the minimum value in the columns (`{'Thur': 7.51, 'Fri': 5.75, 'Sat': 3.07, 'Sun': 7.25}`)
  - [How to get boxplot data for matplotlib boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203735/7758804) shows how to use [`matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats) to extract all the boxplot stats as used by matplotlib.
- `boxplot_stats` works with an array of values containing no `NaN`. In the case of the sample data, each day (comment 1.) does not contain the same number of values, so instead of doing `boxplot_stats(days_total_bill.values)`, a list comprehension (comment 2.) is used to get the stats for each column.
- `tips` is a tidy dataframe, so the relevant data (`'day'` and `'total_bill'`) are pivoted into a wide dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), because `boxplot_stats` needs the data in this form.
- The list of dicts is converted to dataframe (comment 3.), where [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is used to select only the stats to be annotated. This step is done to make it easier to iterate through only the relevant statistics for each day when doing the annotations.
- The data is plotted with [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html), but [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) can also be used.

  - `box_plot = days_total_bill.plot(kind='box', figsize=(12, 8), positions=range(len(days_total_bill.columns)))` where `range` is specified to index from 0, because the default is to index boxplots from 1.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.0.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats

# load sample data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# 1. pivot tips so there's a column for each day for total_bill
days_total_bill = tips.pivot(columns='day', values='total_bill')
# 2. extract the boxplot stats for each day
days_total_bill_stats = [boxplot_stats(days_total_bill[col].dropna().values)[0] for col in days_total_bill.columns]
# 3. create a dataframe for the stats for each day
stats = pd.DataFrame(days_total_bill_stats, index=days_total_bill.columns).iloc[:, [4, 5, 7, 8, 9]].round(2)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
# directly plot the wide dataframe with only the total_bill data
box_plot = sns.boxplot(data=days_total_bill, ax=ax)

# same plot is created with the primary tips dataframe
# box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)

# annotate
for xtick in box_plot.get_xticks():
    for col in stats.columns:
        box_plot.text(xtick, stats[col][xtick], stats[col][xtick], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='k', weight='semibold', bbox=dict(facecolor='lightgray'))
```

[image]

### Data Views

#### `tips`

```
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

#### `days_total_bill`

- not all indices have data

```
day  Thur  Fri  Sat    Sun
0     NaN  NaN  NaN  16.99
1     NaN  NaN  NaN  10.34
2     NaN  NaN  NaN  21.01
3     NaN  NaN  NaN  23.68
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  24.59
...
239    NaN  NaN  29.03  NaN
240    NaN  NaN  27.18  NaN
241    NaN  NaN  22.67  NaN
242    NaN  NaN  17.82  NaN
243  18.78  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

#### `days_total_bill_stats`

```
[{'mean': 17.682741935483868,
  'iqr': 7.712500000000002,
  'cilo': 14.662203087202318,
  'cihi': 17.73779691279768,
  'whishi': 29.8,
  'whislo': 7.51,
  'fliers': array([32.68, 34.83, 34.3 , 41.19, 43.11]),
  'q1': 12.442499999999999,
  'med': 16.2,
  'q3': 20.155},
 {'mean': 17.15157894736842,
  'iqr': 9.655000000000001,
  'cilo': 11.902436010483171,
  'cihi': 18.85756398951683,
  'whishi': 28.97,
  'whislo': 5.75,
  'fliers': array([40.17]),
  'q1': 12.094999999999999,
  'med': 15.38,
  'q3': 21.75},
 {'mean': 20.441379310344825,
  'iqr': 10.835,
  'cilo': 16.4162347275501,
  'cihi': 20.063765272449896,
  'whishi': 39.42,
  'whislo': 3.07,
  'fliers': array([48.27, 44.3 , 50.81, 48.33]),
  'q1': 13.905000000000001,
  'med': 18.24,
  'q3': 24.740000000000002},
 {'mean': 21.41,
  'iqr': 10.610000000000001,
  'cilo': 17.719230764952172,
  'cihi': 21.540769235047826,
  'whishi': 40.55,
  'whislo': 7.25,
  'fliers': array([48.17, 45.35]),
  'q1': 14.987499999999999,
  'med': 19.63,
  'q3': 25.5975}]
```

#### `stats`

```
      whishi  whislo     q1    med     q3
day                                      
Thur   29.80    7.51  12.44  16.20  20.16
Fri    28.97    5.75  12.10  15.38  21.75
Sat    39.42    3.07  13.90  18.24  24.74
Sun    40.55    7.25  14.99  19.63  25.60
```

#### Manual Calculation Doesn't Match Matplotlib Whisker Location

```py
stats = tips.groupby(['day'])['total_bill'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack(level=1).rename({0.25: 'q1', 0.75: 'q3'}, axis=1)
stats.insert(0, 'iqr', stats['q3'].sub(stats['q1']))
stats['w_low'] = stats['q1'].sub(stats['iqr'].mul(1.5))
stats['w_hi'] = stats['q3'].add(stats['iqr'].mul(1.5))
stats = stats.round(2)

        iqr     q1     q3  w_low   w_hi
day                                    
Thur   7.71  12.44  20.16   0.87  31.72
Fri    9.66  12.10  21.75  -2.39  36.23
Sat   10.84  13.90  24.74  -2.35  40.99
Sun   10.61  14.99  25.60  -0.93  41.51
```