# How do you label box plots in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to add the labels for the quartiles and median for Seaborn's boxplots, any ideas?

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="total_bill",y="day", orient='h', data=tips)
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it shows the medians in the duplicate, but it also shows how that is done. So you have to calculate the values for each component (e.g. `medians = tips.groupby(['day'])['total_bill'].median()`) and add them as text annotations.

Comment: See the new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566882/7758804) at the duplicate to correctly locate, and annotate all of the positions (including whiskers)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're still interested I made a quick example model:

Given this generic example boxplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
box = sns.boxplot(x="total_bill",y="day", orient='h', data=tips)
```

From which I look for `min, median and max` values:

```
df1 = tips.groupby('day')['total_bill'].agg(Min='min', Median='median', Max='max')
df1
```

*Do the same for quartiles and/or percentiles*

| day | Min | Median | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thur | 7.51 | 16.2 | 43.11 |
| Fri | 5.75 | 15.38 | 40.17 |
| Sat | 3.07 | 18.24 | 50.81 |
| Sun | 7.25 | 19.63 | 48.17 |

Then iterating over new values to make annotations:

```
for i in range(len(df1.Min)):
  box.annotate(str(df1.Min[i]), xy=(df1.Min[i]-0.1,i), ha='right')

for i in range(len(df1.Median)):
  box.annotate(str(df1.Median[i]), xy=(df1.Median[i]-0.1,i), ha='right')

for i in range(len(df1.Max)):
  box.annotate(str(df1.Max[i]), xy=(df1.Max[i]+0.1,i), ha='left')
```

[image]

**Note:**

*From there you can fully customize size, color, font, vertical/horizontal alignement and so on... :)*