# How to get the values of each median in a boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

The dataset comes from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/anthonypino/melbourne-housing-market).

this code

```
melbourne_file_path = './melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path) 
filtered_melbourne_data = melbourne_data.dropna(axis=0)
ax = filtered_melbourne_data.boxplot(column = 'Price', by = 'Regionname');
```

gives this boxplot

[image]

the boxplot already has lots info, such as median, is there a way to get them corresponding to the `by`s?

I tried this code adapted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33519548)

```
ax, bp = filtered_melbourne_data.boxplot(column = 'Price', by = 'Regionname', return_type='both');
```

and got this error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I also tried this code adapted from that post.

```
ax = filtered_melbourne_data.boxplot(column = 'Price', by = 'Regionname', return_type='both');
print(ax.median)
```

and got

```
<bound method Series.median of Price    (AxesSubplot(0.1,0.15;0.8x0.75), {'whiskers': ...
dtype: object>
```

how to get the values of medians of each `Regionname`?

Comment: It's not very straightforward to retrieve those values from the boxplot object. I would advise you extract them separately with `filtered_melbourne_data.groupby('Regionname').Price.agg('median')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but need some changes in solution from post:

First add `['Price']` for get values form one element `Series`:

```
ax, bp = filtered_melbourne_data.boxplot(column = 'Price', 
                                         by = 'Regionname', 
                                         return_type='both')['Price']
```

And then get first value of arrays by indexing - `[0]`:

```
medians = [median.get_ydata()[0] for median in bp["medians"]]
print (medians)
[990000.0, 670000.0, 715000.0, 590000.0, 780000.0, 1230000.0, 700000.0, 400000.0]
```